# Add event to android calendar but without being prompt(no popup)

Tags: android, events, calendar

I have the following code that works.

But I do not want the confirmation to appear

Want it to automatically enter the event on the calendar

Someone has a suggestion

```
calIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
                            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY
                            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
                    calIntent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");    
                    calIntent.putExtra(Events.TITLE, "SMS: "+contact); 
                    calIntent.putExtra(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, ""); 
                    calIntent.putExtra(Events.DESCRIPTION, msgBody); 
                    calIntent.putExtra(Events.HAS_ALARM, 0);
                    calIntent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_ALL_DAY, false); 
                    calIntent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, System.currentTimeMillis()); 
                    calIntent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, System.currentTimeMillis()+1); 
                    context.startActivity(calIntent);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By using an intent you're handing control over to the calendar application in order to create the actual event. The calendar app determines how to handle the intent, in this case by throwing a confirmation pop-up.

Whilst using an intent is the recommended way of interacting with a user's calendar, you can also do so directly. This will cut out the call to the calendar app and avoid the popup. The downside is that you'll need to request calendar permissions to do so.

Here's the example from the [Calendar Provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html#add-event) tutorial page:

```
long calID = 3;
long startMillis = 0; 
long endMillis = 0;     
Calendar beginTime = Calendar.getInstance();
beginTime.set(2012, 9, 14, 7, 30);
startMillis = beginTime.getTimeInMillis();
Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance();
endTime.set(2012, 9, 14, 8, 45);
endMillis = endTime.getTimeInMillis();
...

ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(Events.DTSTART, startMillis);
values.put(Events.DTEND, endMillis);
values.put(Events.TITLE, "Jazzercise");
values.put(Events.DESCRIPTION, "Group workout");
values.put(Events.CALENDAR_ID, calID);
values.put(Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, "America/Los_Angeles");
Uri uri = cr.insert(Events.CONTENT_URI, values);

// get the event ID that is the last element in the Uri
long eventID = Long.parseLong(uri.getLastPathSegment());
// 
// ... do something with event ID
//
//
```

Comment: `getContentResolver()` is an instance method on `Context`. I assumed you were in an Activity, where it would work. You'll need to get hold of a context from somewhere. If you're in `onReceive()` it should be passed in as a parameter.